# Не могу разобраться с strtok

Tags: c, строки, strtok

не могу разобраться со strtok. Задача такова, от клиента получаю команду и ее нужно разобрать по сепаратору пробела, также сохранив искомую команду, к примеру: есть команда **/server get info**

```
int main()
{
  char string[256] = "/server get info";
  memmove(string, string + 1, strlen(string)); // Убираю первый символ, он не нужен

  char *fetcher = strtok(string, " ");

  printf("--> string: %s\n", string);
  printf("--> fetcher %s\n", fetcher);
  return 0;
}
```

В итоге получаю вывод:

```
--> string: server
--> fetcher server
```

Но нужно чтобы ход программы не изменял переменную **string**, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такова природа strtok - он изменяет исходную строку. Если же нужно, что бы этого не было - скопируйте себе строку в отдельный буфер.

Кстати, если первый символ не нужен, то не обязательно перемещать всю строку, можно просто подвинуть указатель на один символ. Просто посмотрите на этот пример

```
char string[256] = "/server get info";
const char * z = string;
z++;
puts(z);
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, можете показать пример относительно сдвига указателя? Я не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно, чтобы исходная строка не изменялась, то прекратите пользоваться деструктивными функциями, которые ее изменяют. В частности - `strtok`.

Как именно это будет выглядеть в вашем случае - зависит от того, что вы потом собираетесь делать с этими строками. Из вашего синтетического примера это не ясно

```
const char *fetcher = string;
size_t n_fetcher = strcspn(fetcher, " ");
printf("--> string: %s\n", string);
printf("--> fetcher %.*s\n", (int) n_fetcher, fetcher);
```